# 'mysql: unrecognized service' and 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket' after installation of mysql on Debian

Tags: mysql, debian

I am trying to install and run mysql on Debian 11. So far I have been successful with the installation, everything goes smoothly without error and I can see most of the config files. But then when I try to start the service, I get an error `mysql: unrecognized service`.

I tried with both `sudo service mysql status` and `sudo service mysqld status`, same issue. Also, there is nothing related to mysql under `/etc/init.d/` folder.

Also, if I try `mysql -u root -p`, I get an error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And indeed the file does not exist. The folder `/var/run/mysqld/` does exist, but it is empty.

I have a `/etc/mysql/` folder with config files in it and a `/var/lib/mysql/` folder.

Here are the steps I used for the installation:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-server_8.0.31-1debian11_amd64.deb
echo "mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-product select Ok" | debconf-set-selections
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_8.0.31-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-apt-config
sudo apt-get update

echo "mysql-community-server mysql-server/root_password password my_password" | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-server/root_password_again password my_password" | debconf-set-selections
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

I have combed the internet and tried every possible fix I could find, but no luck. Does anyone have any idea of what could be wrong with my installation ?

Thanks a lot !